# Getting Radio Button's Input to a Variable [Tkinter]

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I have several radio buttons which have different values, and are tight to one variable. Even though the variable should take button's value when selected, it doesn't. Here is the code I'm using.

```py
mimeType = StringVar()

wave = StringVar(value="audio/wav")
mp3 = StringVar(value='audio/mp3')
mp4 = StringVar(value='audio/mp4')
mp2 = StringVar(value='audio/mp2')
flac = StringVar(value='audio/flac')
m4a = StringVar(value='audio/m4a')

MP3 = Radiobutton(window, text = "MP3 Format", variable = mimeType,
                  height=5,
                  width = 20, value=mp3,bg = "#36DEE5", activebackground= "#36DEE5",
                 
MP4 = Radiobutton(window, text = "MP4 Format", variable = mimeType,
                  height=5,
                  width = 20,value=mp4,bg = "#36DEE5", activebackground= "#36DEE5")

MP2 = Radiobutton(window, text = "MP2 Format", variable = mimeType,
                  height=5,
                  width = 20,value=mp2,bg = "#36DEE5", activebackground= "#36DEE5")
WAV = Radiobutton(window, text = "WAV Format", variable = mimeType,
                  height=5,
                  width = 20, value=wave,bg = "#36DEE5", activebackground= "#36DEE5")
M4A = Radiobutton(window, text = "M4A Format", variable = mimeType,
                  height=5,
                  width = 20,value=m4a,bg = "#36DEE5", activebackground= "#36DEE5",
                 

print(mimeType.get()) # This doesn't return anything either
```

**Special note:** `print(mimeType.get())` doesn't return anything!

So what I want is, the variable `mimeType` should take the value of Radio Buttons when selected.

Comment: Your print statement runs about a millisecond after creating the radiobuttons.

Comment: You haven't included the code for the `setMimetype()` function in your question. Regardless, you're executing it each time you create a `Radiobutton` — is that intentional?

Comment: Oh sorry, but I'm not using that function further, it's not working well. Will remove it

Comment: You didn't remove it properly — the code in your question is now invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a runnable answer.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
mimeType = StringVar()  # is a string variable but in the original code mimeType was being set an object.
mimeType.set('Initialize')  # So the later print statement will print something

# original code value = was being set to objects.
wave = StringVar(value="audio/wav")  # These are objects no longer needed?
mp3 = StringVar(value='audio/mp3')  # These are objects no longer needed?
mp4 = StringVar(value='audio/mp4')  # These are objects no longer needed?
mp2 = StringVar(value='audio/mp2')  # These are objects no longer needed?
flac = StringVar(value='audio/flac')  # These are objects no longer needed?
m4a = StringVar(value='audio/m4a')  # These are objects no longer needed?


def display_current_mimetype():
    print(mimeType.get())


# Remove assignment of Radiobutton from original code unless the created
# objects are needed later.

# Modify code to value = string not value = object
Radiobutton(window, text="MP3 Format", variable=mimeType,
            height=5,
            width=20, value='audio/mp3', bg="#36DEE5",
            activebackground="#36DEE5", command=display_current_mimetype).pack(
    anchor=W)

Radiobutton(window, text="MP4 Format", variable=mimeType,
            height=5,
            width=20, value='audio/mp4', bg="#36DEE5",
            activebackground="#36DEE5", command=display_current_mimetype).pack(
    anchor=W)

Radiobutton(window, text="MP2 Format", variable=mimeType,
            height=5,
            width=20, value='audio/mp2', bg="#36DEE5",
            activebackground="#36DEE5", command=display_current_mimetype).pack(
    anchor=W)
Radiobutton(window, text="WAV Format", variable=mimeType,
            height=5,
            width=20, value="audio/wav", bg="#36DEE5",
            activebackground="#36DEE5", command=display_current_mimetype).pack(
    anchor=W)
Radiobutton(window, text="M4A Format", variable=mimeType,
            height=5,
            width=20, value='audio/m4a', bg="#36DEE5",
            activebackground="#36DEE5", command=display_current_mimetype).pack(
    anchor=W)

print(mimeType.get())  # Will print the initial value

mainloop()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

The `value` parameter doesn't take an `IntVar()` or a `StringVar()` object. You can directly assign a string or integer to it.

`print(mimeType.get())` would then print the `value` stored in `mimeType`.

The second problem is that your print statement is executed even before the user can click on a radiobutton.

There are two solutions to the above problem.

1. Create a button that displays the chosen value when the user clicks on the button.
2. Use the `command` parameter to call a function (which displays the value chosen) when the user clicks on a radiobutton.

**Sample code for the second solution:**

```py
MP4 = Radiobutton(window, text = "MP4 Format", variable = mimeType, height=5, width = 20,value = 'audio/mp4', bg = "#36DEE5", activebackground= "#36DEE5", command = lambda : print(mimeType.get()))
```

Add `command = lambda : print(mimeType.get())` to all the radiobuttons to print out the `value` as soon as the user clicks on a radiobutton.

Comment: this is part of the problem. The other part is that the `print` statement happens before the user sees the radiobutton so it's going to print the default value.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: I guess this is the problem! But then, how can I call it after the user sees the radio button? I placed it after those lines but not working, it's returning the default one. How can I keep it updated?

Comment: JKR: You're now asking a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions @Siram Srinivasan! However, when I tried the second solution, it does return the value but in these ways— `PY_VAR0`, `PY_VAR3`, `PY_VAR2`. What should I do about this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you missed out `.get()`. You need to call the get method to access the value it represents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're setting up the `Radiobutton`s incorrectly. Setting their `var=` option to a StringVar isn't right, you should set it to the value you want assigned to the `mimeType` `StringVar` when the `Radiobutton` is selected.

Here's a runnable example of what I mean. Note I have renamed several of your variable and reformatted the code to more closely follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

MP3 = 'audio/mp3'
MP4 = 'audio/mp4'
MP2 = 'audio/mp2'
WAVE = 'audio/wav'
FLAC = 'audio/flac'
M4A = 'audio/m4a'
mimeType = StringVar(value='N/A')
BUTTON_OPTS = dict(height=1, width=20, bg='#36DEE5', activebackground= '#36DEE5',
                   variable=mimeType, command=lambda: print(mimeType.get()))

mp3_btn = Radiobutton(window, text='MP3 Format', value=MP3, **BUTTON_OPTS)
mp3_btn.pack()
mp4_btn = Radiobutton(window, text='MP4 Format', value=MP4, **BUTTON_OPTS)
mp4_btn.pack()
mp2_btn = Radiobutton(window, text='MP2 Format', value=MP2, **BUTTON_OPTS)
mp2_btn.pack()
wav_btn = Radiobutton(window, text='WAV Format', value=WAVE, **BUTTON_OPTS)
wav_btn.pack()
flac_btn = Radiobutton(window, text='FLAC Format', value=FLAC, **BUTTON_OPTS)
flac_btn.pack()
m4a_btn = Radiobutton(window, text='M4A Format', value=M4A, **BUTTON_OPTS)
m4a_btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like running:

[image: screenshot]